How can I layout my roofing shingles to look even on the ends?
How do the pros layout the shingles so the ends look about the same size?


About the same size as what? The opposite ends?

I got a much more attractive result by making each row end with either a full shingle or a half.

Are you really installing three-tab shingles in 2024? Even if you prefer the classic appearance, they won't last nearly as long. With the somewhat random tab arrangement of modern laminated shingles this issue goes away.

@A.I.Breveleri, is your roof sized for your singles? It's a rare and wonderful coincidence when that works out on both ends. However, the imperfection of most roofs and the fact that the waterlines in three-tab shingles have a width mean you're more likely to have a jagged final appearance than the holy grail you describe.

@isherwood: No. I start from the ends and work toward the middle. Then I make the joint at a different place in each row. The odd-sized shingles end up scattered all over the roof. - If the joint results in a silly little finger of a shingle then I make two joints in that row.

With three-tabs? That would look ridiculous.

You might be right. Maybe it looks good only on a small area.

I suppose one must decide whether a roof with symmetrical shingles is worth having to cut both end sheets of shingles on every single course, instead of just one sheet.

@A. I. Breveleri  SOrry for delay:  Yes, opposite equal.

@isherwood No.  Architectural - to match the house.  That is what is on the shed now

Start from the center of the roof:
Measure the roof length and divide by two. That divided measurement is half of the roof length. Go that far along the roof and make a vertical line up the roof slope: this line is the center of the roof and is where you'll start the tiles.
On one row, place the center of a roof tile at the center line of the roof. Continue placing tiles both sides until you reach the ends of the roof.
On the next row, place two tiles side by side, with the center joint between them on the center line of the roof. Continue placing tiles both sides until you reach the ends of the roof.
Repeat these two methods (center of one tile, then center of two tiles...) until the roof is covered. If you measured and marked accurately, the tiles will be equal length on each end of the roof.

Be advised that this can result in very slim end tabs, which are more prone to damage over time. Lay the row out completely and see how it works out. I wouldn't want end tabs less than say 3 inches wide.

Saw a video where a guy started with the video, it ended with small ends, so he moved it over "half a plank" which makes both sides larger, FWIW: https://youtu.be/FMF0JcwSPKc?t=68

I haven't done a roof but I have done a porch and couple of sheds. I use the three-tab shingles because that's what's on the main building.
I got a much more attractive result by making each row end with either a full shingle or a half.
I start from the ends and work toward the middle. Then I make the joint at a different place in each row. The odd-sized shingles end up scattered all over the roof.
If the joint results in a silly little finger of a shingle then I make two joints in that row.
EDIT: Thanks to a remark by @isherwood I now suspect that this method might look good only on small areas like the porch and sheds I did. On a full-size house roof there might be large areas where the waterlines line up contrasted with rows where they are offset.
